# Case conditional in ruby doesn't enter in when

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, conditional-statements, httparty

My code when executed it's not entering in the when loop inside the case conditional.
What I wanted is to sen two different GET requests based on the *args of the function.
So I can validate the errors when I don't send one of the parameters in the request.
If someone have a better logic to do it one method, I appreaciate as well.

Here is my code:

```
def get_function(access_token,order1,order2,*args)
    case args
      when  args = "order1"
        self.class.get("/v1/apiendpoint?order2=#{order2}",
                   headers: {'accesstoken': "#{access_token}"})
      when args = "order2"
        self.class.get("/v1/apiendpoint?order1=#{order1}",
                   headers: {'accesstoken': "#{access_token}"})
    end
  end
```

When I execute with binding.pry (debugging) it shows this part, and doesn't execute the rest of the code.

```
From: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-8.0.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/action.rb @ line 25 Cucumber::Core::Test::Action#execute:

22: def execute(*args)
23:   @timer.start
24:   @block.call(*args)
==> 25:   passed
26: rescue Result::Raisable => exception
27:   exception.with_duration(@timer.duration)
28: rescue Exception => exception
29:   failed(exception)
30: end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems here:

```
case args
when  args = "order1"
```

Firstly, `args` is an `Array` - so it cannot possibly be equal to a `String`. I'm not sure what you intended to happen here, so can't say exactly how to fix it.

Secondly, `=` is an **assignment** operator, whereas `==` performs an equality check.

And lastly, this is a `case` statement, not an `if` statement, so you shouldn't actually be performing an equality check here... Either of these would have made sense syntactically:

```
case args
when "order1"
   # ...
end

# OR:

case
when args == "order1"
  # ...
end
```

---

Also, note that your question description is a bit confusing. You said:

> the when loop

but this is not a loop. You could call it a "clause", or a "statement", but it's certainly not a "loop".

Answer (score 1):

Following Tom help, decided to go with `IF` statement.

Here is what worked:

```
def get_function(access_token,order1,order2,*args)

 if args == ["order1"]
          self.class.get("/v1/apiendpoint?order2=#{order2}",
            headers: {'accesstoken': "#{access_token}"})
            else
              self.class.get("/v1/apiendpoint?order1=#{order1}",
                headers: {'accesstoken': "#{access_token}"})
        end
```

Comment: I think I hadn't quite understood the question when I answered. Are you trying to check whether the user provided a value for the parameter `order1`, or whether the user provided the **`String`** `"order1"` as a parameter to the function?

Comment: hey...second option. If it receives `"order1"` do something...

Comment: Alright, so my answer applies conceptually, as I'm checking for `String` equality :)

Answer (score 1):

`args` is an `Array` of arguments, so comparing it to a `String` will always evaluate to `false`, no matter the `String`.

I don't know exactly what you need in terms of the behaviour of the function, but what I *can* say is that if you want to look inside the `args` `Array` to compare every argument to a `String`, it might be a better idea to **iterate** over the array.

**Example with `if`:**

```
def args_example(*args)
  # Working directly with *args doesn't work, so we assign it to arguments
  arguments = *args

  # We need a way to save the output after the if clause
  output = []

  # Let's iterate!
  arguments.each do |argument|

    # This is where the if would come in
    if argument == "One"
      output << 1
    elsif argument == "Two"
      output << 2
    else
      output << 0
    end
  end

  output
end
```

```
args_example("One", "Two", "Three")

=> [1, 2, 0]
```

**Example with `case`:**

```
def args_example(*args)
  # Working directly with *args doesn't work, so we assign it to arguments
  arguments = *args
  
  # We need a way to save the output after the case clause
  output = []

  # Let's iterate!
  arguments.each do |argument|

    # This is where the case would come in
    case argument
    when "One"
      output << 1
    when "Two"
      output << 2
    else
      output << 0
    end
  end

  output
end
```

```
args_example("One", "Two", "Three")

=> [1, 2, 0]
```

This is **one** way to check all the arguments provided to the function (there's surely a shorter way) and send a `GET` request accordingly.

Cheers!

**NOTE:** I saved the output to be able to display it, but I realised that since you're only performing a `GET` request, you don't need to do that. Simply execute the request instead of saving the output.